# lotus designer how to get address from Mail-in name

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

my lotus agent detachs the files and put them into the different folders base on the **destinations** of mail (destinations = array type). Actually, it works almost well but it doesn't work with **Mail-in name**

```
found = False
If IsArray(curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo")) Then
    ForAll elt In curdoc.GetItemValue("SendTo")
        idxFolder = 0
        ForAll dest In destinations
            If InStr(1,CStr(elt),CStr(dest),5) <> 0 Then
                found = True
                Exit ForAll
            End If
            idxFolder = idxFolder + 1
        End ForAll
    End ForAll
    If found Then
        Exit ForAll
    End If
End If
```

Ex:
On Mail-In Database, i have

- Mail-in name = TEST MAIL
- Domain = INTRANET
- Internet addresse = test@xyz.com*

when I send a mail with destination = "TEST MAIL@INTRANET", my agent doesn't detach the file because in loop 2nd, i got "TEST MAIL@INTRANET" instead of "test@xyz.com"

my question: how could i get mail address from Mail-in name?

thanks a lot
best regards
dsea

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a lookup in the $Users view of the Domino Directory.  (Note: $Users does include mail-in databases, not just users.)

But it's not as simple as just opening names.nsf and doing a `getDocumentByKey` in the $Users view.  It's more complicated than that because your Domino server may have multiple Domino Directories configured. So I believe you should be using `NotesSession.getDirectory`, and then the `LookupNames` method of the `NotesDirectory` class.  See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html).  The doc may lead you to believe that you have to search for a username, but actually  the first column in $Users contains many variations of a user's "name" -- including the InternetAddress, so they are all searchable.  You should be able to search on that and find the FullName field (which is in the third column of $Users, with programmatic name "FullName").  The return will be a `NotesDirectoryNavigator` object, so you'll need to use the methods of that class to actually get your result.

Comment: Just to add, lookupNames is a lot safer then a view lookup. Because if you hit a condensed directory the code will likely barf.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question and code properly, you are mapping values from the SendTo field to values stored in the Array destinations. The easiest way to resolve this issue would be to add the notes-internal E-Mail address of Mail-In-Databases to the array ("TEST MAIL@INTRANET" instead of the Internet address "test@xyz.com").

Otherwise you could try using the InetSendTo field. It contains the Internet Mail Address of the recipients.

EDIT: 
The best and most reliable way to resolve what you are looking for is doing a lookup to the domino directory to get the internet address in case you have the Mailin-Name only.

Comment: i ready though this point and i setted both "TEST MAIL@INTRANET" AND "test@xyz.com" into destinations array but it isn't the best way!!! I will try InetSendTo. Thanks

Comment: with InetSendTo, in case "Send" to "TEST MAIL@INTRANET", it is "test@xyz.com" so OK. But in the case "Forward" to "TEST MAIL@INTRANET", it is "." so it doesn't work